# Difference between dispose and exit on close in java

Tags: java

I have a single frame created using Netbeans GUI builder when I view the frame properties one of the first options is default close operation the options listed are: `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`, `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` & `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` I understand the middle two but, whats the difference between `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` and `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` ? I have tried testing both but to me they do the same thing to me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`EXIT_ON_CLOSE` will terminate the program.

`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` will call `dispose()` on the frame, which will make it disappear and remove the resources it is using.  You cannot bring it back, unlike hiding it.

See aslo [JFrame.dispose() vs System.exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360430/jframe-dispose-vs-system-exit)

Comment: It removes the resources it is using.  You cannot bring it back, unlike hiding it.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a few JFrames open and you close the one that is set to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`then all of the frames will be closed.

The opposite applies to the one with the `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` i.e. only it will be closed

Answer (score 1):

DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE - Disposes the window when it's closed. You cannot redisplay the window, although the object window is still available in the memory

Comment: "although the object window is still available in the memory".=> it still *uses* memory (until it is garbage collected). Saying it is "available" is confusing at least. And yet another thing: you *can* redisplay the window, though it will require recreating it (using the `new` keyword).