# How to only get my Pop-up JFrame to close

Tags: java, user-interface, oop, jframe

I have created two classes. One is my main GUI the other is my popup GUI which is launced via a button click.

How ever when i click the close button on my popup GUI it closes all the JFrames.

Here is my main GUI

```
public FirstAid() {
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBounds(100, 100, 700, 507);
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(contentPane);
contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
```

My popup GUI also has the

```
EXIT_ON_CLOSE
```

Comment: You can use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` instead of `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`

Comment: You could try to change EXIT_ON_CLOSE to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want, as mentioned in the comments is `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`. And here's why:

`EXIT_ON_CLOSE` will terminate the program.

`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` will call dispose() on the frame, which will make the [single] frame disappear and remove the resources that it's using.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433358/difference-between-dispose-and-exit-on-close-in-java)