# How to go back to my login screen?

Tags: java, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenubar

My program is written in Java using Eclipse and what my program does is first you have to login your username and password to the server and once that is verified, then you go to a new page (frame) where I have a JMenuBar, JMenu, and JMenuItem. The JMenuItem that I am working on is called "Logout" under the JMenu Exit, when you click on logout at the moment, it closes the screen. What I want to happen is to redirect me back to the login page. I've tried many functions, but none of them worked. I would appreciate the help.

Here is my program:

```
public class ScanTest2 extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static LoginDialog loginDialog;

public ScanTest2() {
    loginDialog = new LoginDialog(this, true);
    loginDialog.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    { 

        public void run() 
        {
            // create new frame for new page
            JFrame frame = new ScanTest2();

            //create a Menu bar
            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            try {
                frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("/home/a002384/logo2.bmp")))));

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            frame.setTitle("Scan Gun Information");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

            // create Menus
            JMenu databaseMenu = new JMenu("Database");
            JMenu ticketMenu = new JMenu("Tickets");
            JMenu inquiriesMenu = new JMenu("Inquiries");
            JMenu reportsMenu = new JMenu("Reports");
            JMenu exitMenu = new JMenu("Exit");

            // create Menu Items
            JMenuItem lotMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Lots");
                lotMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_L);
                lotMenuItem.setActionCommand("Lots");
            JMenuItem gunMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Guns");
                gunMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_G);
                gunMenuItem.setActionCommand("Guns");
            JMenuItem batteryMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Batteries");
                batteryMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
                batteryMenuItem.setActionCommand("Batteries");
            JMenuItem logoutMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Logout");
                logoutMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_L);
                logoutMenuItem.setActionCommand("Logout");


            MenuItemListener menuItemListener = new MenuItemListener();
            lotMenuItem.addActionListener(menuItemListener);
            gunMenuItem.addActionListener(menuItemListener);
            batteryMenuItem.addActionListener(menuItemListener);
            logoutMenuItem.addActionListener(menuItemListener);

            // add Menu Items to Menus
            databaseMenu.add(lotMenuItem);
            databaseMenu.add(gunMenuItem);
            databaseMenu.add(batteryMenuItem);
            exitMenu.add(logoutMenuItem);

            // add menu to MenuBar
            menuBar.add(databaseMenu);
            menuBar.add(ticketMenu);
            menuBar.add(inquiriesMenu);
            menuBar.add(reportsMenu);
            menuBar.add(exitMenu);

            frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        } // end of run method

        class MenuItemListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String command = e.getActionCommand();
                if (command.equals("Logout"))
                    System.exit(0);
                    // go back to login screen

            }   
        }
    }); // end of Runnable
}// end of Main
}

class LoginDialog extends JDialog {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private final JLabel loginlbl = new JLabel("Username");
private final JLabel Passwordlbl = new JLabel("Password");

private final JTextField loginName = new JTextField(15);
private final JPasswordField loginPassword = new JPasswordField();

private final JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
private final JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

private final JLabel Status = new JLabel(" ");

private String username;
private String password;

private int m_errCounter = 0;

public static final int MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 3;

public LoginDialog() {
    this(null, true);
}

public LoginDialog(final JFrame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);

    JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    p3.add(loginlbl);
    p3.add(Passwordlbl);

    JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    p4.add(loginName);
    p4.add(loginPassword);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.add(p3);
    p1.add(p4);

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.add(loginButton);
    p2.add(cancelButton);

    JPanel p5 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p5.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    p5.add(Status, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    Status.setForeground(Color.RED);
    Status.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p5, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    loginPassword.enableInputMethods(true);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {  

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {  
            System.exit(0);  
        }  
    });

    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            UniJava uJava = new UniJava();
            try {
                    username = loginName.getText();
                    password = new String (loginPassword.getPassword());
                    if (username == " " && password == " ") 
                    {
                        Status.setText("Invalid username or password!");
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        UniSession session = uJava.openSession();
                        session.setHostName("docdbtst.starcalif.com");
                        session.setUserName(username);
                        session.setPassword(password);
                        session.setAccountPath("/mnt/data1/DD");
                        session.connect();
                        parent.setVisible(true);
                        setVisible(false);
                    }

            } catch (UniSessionException e1) {

                if (++m_errCounter > MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginDialog.this, 
                            "All Login attempts failed!", 
                            "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    Status.setText("Invalid Login! Cannot Connect!");
                    loginName.setText("");
                    loginPassword.setText("");
                }

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }   
    });
    cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setVisible(false);
            parent.dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: From what I see, after the login is successful you set `setVisible(false)` on the login dialog, which means it's still in the background, just invisible. If this is the case, just use `setVisible(true)` for it when you want to return to that "page". Note that this will retain the state of the dialog since it was not recreated, just re-shown.

Comment: I would dispose of the log-in JPanel once the credentials have been verified, rather than just hiding it. Technically a security issue. Instantiating a new one on logout is the course of action I'd recommend.

Comment: @Compass How should I go about that route?

Comment: @c.torres Similar to the answer that Jake has provided below. When you log-in, you should dispose of the login screen instead of `setVisible(false)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.exit()` everything will be cleaned up
[JFrame.dispose() vs System.exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360430/jframe-dispose-vs-system-exit)

```
logoutItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            f.dispose();
            // northInformation.removeAll();
            // init();
            LoginWindow login = new LoginWindow();
        }
    });
```

Comment: How should I do this in my program then?

Comment: Change `System.exit(0)` to `f.dispose()`, f is the window you want to close.