# Swing check if a window is opened

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a program with 2 classes that each create 1 window. The first window has a button that opens the second one and I wanted a way to check when the second window is opened so that the user can't close the first one.

Comment: Please, fix the typo in the title and add the Java code you are using, stripping it of any unnecessary methods.

Comment: Using isVisible() should help you.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a program with 2 classes that each create 1 window.

By tagging [jframe](/questions/tagged/jframe) I'm going to assume that those are what you call "window".

> The first window has a button that opens the second one

You [don't want mutiple `JFrame`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) in your application. What you want is a `JDialog` (or a `JOptionPane`).

> and I wanted a way to check when the second window is opened so that the user can't close the first one.

What you actually want is a [modal dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html). Generally speaking, ff the dialog is modal, you can't interact with its parent while it is open.

So when you press the button in `frame1`, you will want to call the following constructor:

```
JDialog(Dialog owner, boolean modal)
```

with `frame1` and `true`. `JOptionPane` is modal by default. See [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Answer (score 0):

While closing the frame, use `JFrame.dispose()` function instead of System.exit() and you may also use `JFrame.getFrames()` or `JFrame.getWindows()` to get references of all the active windows and exit if the count is zero.

For more understanding you may visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360430/jframe-dispose-vs-system-exit]) too.