# FileDialog hanging on Mac OS in JFX Application

Tags: java, macos, freeze, macos-catalina, filedialog

So far, I've tried to run this on a fresh Mojave, and my main Catalina installation with the same hanging results. The code snippet to open FileDialog runs fine independently in a separate project, but if I create another class in the same package and call it like that, it's the same deal - still hanging. It's being called within the controller if that makes a difference (I've tried JFileChooser which also hangs, and seems to have a history of hanging on OS X. To reiterate I also tried extracting the code to open the dialog to a different class aswell.) It hangs when it reaches `fd.setVisible(true);`. I've tried disabling iCloud as I've heard that can cause issues, I've also disabled SIPS as a test. I'm not even sure how I can debug this further now. Any help would be super appreciated!

```
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");
            FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame, "Choose a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
            fd.setVisible(true);
            String filename = fd.getFile();
            System.out.println(filename);
```

Comment: Try setting the frame visiable first `frame.setVisible(true);`

Comment: I actually had tried that before, but just tried it again for good measure, but still no dice!

Answer (score 0):

OMG. It only took me all day, but I only needed to make the FileDialog run on it's own thread. Hopefully this'll save some other noob's time lol. My new code looks like this:

```
public class threadTest extends Thread {
    public void run(){  
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        System.setProperty("com.apple.macos.use-file-dialog-packages", "true");
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame, "choose_file", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setVisible(true);
        String filename = fd.getFile();
      }    
}
```

and I called it like this

```
 threadTest test=new threadTest();   
 test.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute `dispose()` on the JFrame and FileDialog when finished. e.g.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
System.setProperty("com.apple.macos.use-file-dialog-packages", "true");
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame, "choose_file", FileDialog.LOAD);
fd.setVisible(true);
String filename = fd.getFile();           
frame.dispose();
fd.dispose();
```

Alternatively, you can try `System.exit()`. e.g.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
System.setProperty("com.apple.macos.use-file-dialog-packages", "true");
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame, "choose_file", FileDialog.LOAD);
fd.setVisible(true);
String filename = fd.getFile();           
System.exit();
```

There is some debate as to which approach is better [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360430/jframe-dispose-vs-system-exit).